# Filter the dataframe of having multiple ID<PKs> columns by passing the values of each IDs in a list

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**Trying to filter the dataframe of having multiple ID columns by passing the values of each IDs in a list.**

For eg: Df:

```
location_user
transactiontime (string)
user_id (bigint)
location_id (bigint)
Address1 (string)
Address2 (string)
user_name (string)
loc_name (string)
```

In the above Dataframe: user_id and location_id both are ID columns.

**GOAL:  filter user_id=[42939,42940] and location_id=[1468,1469] against the Dataframe.**

Created the separate list as below and applied them on df.filter.

```
partition_key =['user_id', 'location_id']
filter_cond = ['[42939,42940]', '[1468,1469]']
```

---> working for single partition_key

```
filter_df=actual_df.filter(~col(partition_key).isin(filter_cond))
```

Tried to the below for combination of partition_key but it's not working and having the below error.

```
filter_df=actual_df.filter(~col(partition_key).isInCollection(filter_cond))
```

> Error: Error occured during overwriting the directory. Please check if
> correct parameters is passed. Exception:  An error occurred while
> calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col. Trace:
> py4j.Py4JException: Method col([class java.util.ArrayList]) does not
> exist

Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by zipping the conditions like

```
partition_key =['id', 'id2']
filter_cond = [[1,2], [100,200]]
cond = ' AND '.join([f'{colname} in {tuple(cond)}' for colname, cond in zip(partition_key,filter_cond)])
print(cond)

df.filter(expr(cond)).show()

#id in (1, 2) AND id2 in (100, 200)
#+---+---+
#| id|id2|
#+---+---+
#|  1|100|
#|  1|200|
#|  2|100|
#|  2|200|
#+---+---+
```

**Update for single element**

```
cond = ' AND '.join([f'{colname} in ({",".join(map(str,a))})' for colname, cond in zip(partition_key,filter_cond)])
```

Comment: Hi Shubham, Thanks for your response. I have tried and this time I used the below filter PARTITION KEYS: ['user_id', 'location_id'] and [[17954], [3350]] it has single value in the list. But it failed due excess comma in the condition" (17954,) AND location_id in (3350,)". However It's working fine for list with more than one column. Really very thanks.